# Move TFS 2012 Project Collection to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, migration, downgrade

Is it possible to move TFS 2012 Project Collection to TFS 2010 on different server?

When I tried to detach it from 2012 and attach to 2010 as this article says:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I encountered with the next error:

> TF246091: The team project collection cannot be attached because its version ID is higher than the ID for the configuration database. The collection has the following version: Dev11.RTM. The Team Foundation Server is at the following version: TFS2010.RTM.KB2135068.P#3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Team Foundation Server Integration Tools (March 2012 Release)`: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

> The TFS Integration Tools is a project developed by the Team
>   Foundation Server (TFS) product group and the Visual Studio ALM
>   Rangers to integrate Team Foundation Server with third party systems
>   for migration and synchronization of data.

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all: it is not possible. Every new release change the database schema and there is no way of "rolling it back" only forward.

Comment: May be exist any unsupported way to do it?

Comment: There isn't any unsupported way that I know of (I doubt it's possible).